regex to detect two consecutive lines that have the same words in the same order, but different spaces at leading, trailing and between words
I want to find a regex or perl oneliner to detect two consecutive lines that have the same words in the same order, but the leading spaces, trailing spaces and amount of spaces between the words may vary from one line to the other. The regex must exclude thos lines that don't match.
I use this regex to detect thw identical consecutive lines
^\s*(.*\S)(\s\n*\1)+$  It fails when the amount of whitespace vay from one line to the other.
I have this sample text
Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.
Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

vrfgrgru hfiughf iujhfuihgifughuir nuhuvhfug

Mary has  a little lamb. The live near the mountain.
  Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

 Mary has a little lamb.  The live near the mountain.
Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

fghurhg bojghirejyohi ndhguhyituhgi
gbshbsiughsf bnighriugh hurhgiurhgriu

 Elvis was the greatest singer of all time. He has 18 number one in billboard charts.
Elvis was the greatest singer  of all time. He has 18 number one in billboard charts.

sgfuhgdugusd vfjsng orjgoergo ejfio dsmnjn
fbdhsbfgdbhhbfhdsfdf

Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.
 Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

gsete gerttrb oijoijoijoijoijoiojo gogoerijoi

jhoiyrei  erogjrijgtrio noifdo mkooi 

This has been the coldest winter in the last 20 years.
 This has  been the coldest winter in the  last 20 years.

Regardless of the number of spaces in the lines, the regex should display the consecutive lines that contain the same information.
There aren't three in a row and there aren't empty lines between the matching lines.

what if there are three in a row?

And do you consider two consecutive lines still "consecutive" if there's an empty line in between them? It so happens that you split groups of two "matching" lines using empty lines, so I wonder.

There aren't three in a row and there aren't empty lines between the matching lines.

Is there, in effect, just gibberish and empty lines between the desired lines and is what you want to print everything except for the said gibberish and empty lines? Either way, edit the question and add the expected outside so that what you want is entirely clear.

Please don't change the requirements after an answer has been posted already; changing the requirements in this case has invalidated Ed Morton's (initially correct) answer.

I undid your edit since you are changing what the question asks for but people have already posted an answer.

@SistemasLibsur If the question you asked and got answers to isn't the question you actually meant to ask then accept an answer to the question you asked and ask a new question rather than changing the question you asked and so invalidating the answers you got. If you have a followup question then also just accept an answer and ask a new question as chameleon questions are discouraged.

Well, it's not a regexp and it's not a perl one liner, but this will do what I think you actually want to do using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:
$ awk '{c=$0; $1=$1} k==$0{print p ORS c ORS} {k=$0; p=c}' file
Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.
Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

Mary has  a little lamb. The live near the mountain.
  Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

 Mary has a little lamb.  The live near the mountain.
Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

 Elvis was the greatest singer of all time. He has 18 number one in billboard charts.
Elvis was the greatest singer  of all time. He has 18 number one in billboard charts.

Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.
 Mary has a little lamb. The live near the mountain.

This has been the coldest winter in the last 20 years.
 This has  been the coldest winter in the  last 20 years.

I'm assuming you favor brevity since you asked for a regexp or a perl one-liner but if you prefer legibility, here it is again with more meaningful variable names and better white space:
awk '
    { currRec=$0; $1=$1; currKey=$0 }
    prevKey == currKey { print prevRec ORS currRec ORS } 
    { prevKey=currKey; prevRec=currRec }
' file


Thanks for your answer. I hope to make a new question based on this one to delete these matched lines from the file.
